# sending active parameter from <select> in URL

Tags: html, spring, url, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

I have html form. Three `<select>` tag have data from database.
I want when I press the button a request is sent to a URL that would look like this: 
`/admin/{facultyName}/{specialtyName}/{groupName}` 
Where **facultyName** is the selected value in the first `<select>`, **specialtyName** is the selected value in the second `<select>`, **groupName** is the selected value in the third `<select>`.

Please can you give me an example of how to do this? Any options would be good, with and without form.

 P.S. my attempt:

```
<form name='f' action="#" th:action="@{/admin/(faculty=${facultyName})/(specialty=${specialtyName})/(group=${groupName})}" th:object="${schedule}" method='POST'>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select th:field="*{facultyName}">
                <option value="">Не выбран</option>
                <option th:each="faculty : ${facultyAll}"
                        th:value="${faculty.facultyName}"
                        th:utext="${faculty.facultyName}">
                </option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select th:field="*{specialtyName}">
                <option value="">Не выбран</option>
                <option th:each="specialty : ${specialtyAll}"
                        th:value="${specialty.specialtyName}"
                        th:utext="${specialty.specialtyName}">
                </option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select th:field="*{groupName}">
                <option value="">Не выбран</option>
                <option th:each="group : ${groupAll}"
                        th:value="${group.groupName}"
                        th:utext="${group.groupName}">
                </option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Work with this group"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with Thymeleaf only. Thymeleaf will fill in the `action` attribute when generating the HTML, but will not update it on-the-fly.

You will need to use Javascript to update the `action` attribute dynamically.

Another option would be to have a fixed URL and redirect the user dynamically from the server.

```
@Controller
public class AdminController {

  @GetMapping("/admin/select")
  public String selectAdmin(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("selectionCriteria", new AdminSelectionCriteria());
  }

  @PostMapping("/admin/select")
  public String doSelectAdmin(@ModelAttribute("selectionCriteria") AdminSelectionCriteria criteria) {
    // check the 3 fields in AdminSelectionCriteria
    if( ... )
      return "redirect:/admin/.../";
    else if( ... )
      return "redirect:/admin/../";
    ...
  }
}
```

In the template, you would use:

```
<form name="f" th:action="@{/admin/select}" th:object="selectionCriteria">
```